# Coldfusion 8 & Twitter - cffeed unable to read the source URL. Status Code: 400

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8, cffeed

In Coldfusion 8 Enterprise (8,0,1,195765), the following two lines of code causes this error:

**Unable to read the source URL. Status Code: 400 Try adding or changing UserAgent attribute in the CFFeed tag**

```
<cffeed source="http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/62944327.rss" query="twitter">
<cfdump var="#twitter#">
```

Yet, on my development box with Coldfusion 8 Standard (8,0,0,176276), it's working.... Argh. Any ideas why?

Comment: Hmm... wait fifteen minutes and it works again. Is Twitter just unreliable for RSS feeds? Has anyone else gotten the Status Code 400 from cffeed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure, but possibly it is caused by rate limiting as explained on this page

http://apiwiki.twitter.com/HTTP-Response-Codes-and-Errors

and this page:

http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Rate-limiting

Comment: Looks like you are allowed to ask 150 times per hour. So if you'll be reloading a page for development, or looping over anything, it's best to cache the feed for a period of time to keep under the 150 number.

Answer (score 0):

Does the server running Enterprise have to go through a proxy to get out?  I've had that happen before with cfhttp, it works on dev but not in production because the production box goes out through a proxy and you have to supply the proxy info to make it work.

Comment: Good suggestion to check, but no, it doesn't go through a proxy.